# Unable to install AMD Radeon 7670m graphics driver on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ati, radeon

I can't configure the graphics driver for Radeon 7670m HD for 12.04. I installed latest Catalyst Control Center 12.06, it shows me that the hardware doesn't match the driver.

How can I install driver for my graphics card?

Comment: I had the same problem. Amd radeon 7670m only support ccc 3.0.0.. So just try to install this version.. Otherwise there's another way.. Download the latest driver software from amd official website.. It includes both ccc 12.06 and latest driver version 8.981.0.0. It will support ur driver. After doing all this stuff post ur feed back.

Comment: http://leshcatlabs.net/index.php/2012/07/catalyst-12-7-jun28-official-beta-unifl-for-hybrid-graphics/ Heres the link. Sorry 4 delay. sid...:D

Answer (score 1):

In 12.04 I used amd propietary drivers from: 
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Please check your graphic card with `lspci` or `lspci | grep VGA`

like:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Caicos [Radeon HD 6450]
```

After download driver from amd.com, create deb packages.  and install them with sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb 
Good information about all details for precise: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide

**Example** from upper link:
Download the latest Catalyst package.

This package contains both the 32-bit and 64-bit driver.

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
unzip amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
chmod +x amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run
```

Create and install .deb packages.

```
sudo sh ./amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Since latests ubuntu version I was trying with "software sources" with default packages, the default installation with graphical assistance works really well and much times better than trying to install amd drivers yourself. I recommend to try with default easy support from ubuntu to activate yours drivers.